# How to set memorycache pollinginterval to a subsecond interval

Tags: .net, caching

I've looked on here and google, no answers.
I have a need for caching using the memorycache object with a sliding expiration measured in milliseconds. How do I do this? Is the pollinginterval even the right property to manipulate?